# Data Factory v2 - connecting using REST

Tags: rest, azure-data-factory

The aim is to connect to a public REST api using ADF. It's my first stab at sending requests to a REST api in ADF. It is the Companies House ('CH') governement website's  API in England.

I have created an account and obtained a key.  Apparently, it is basic authentication and the user name is the API key and password will be ignored ([CH note on authentication](https://developer.companieshouse.gov.uk/api/docs/index/gettingStarted/apikey_authorisation.html))

I want to explore the contents of the 'Search all' API ([CH note on Search All](https://developer.companieshouse.gov.uk/api/docs/search/search.html)) and want to copy the results to Blob Storage.

I therefore set the linked service to use REST as below, the obfuscated User Name is the key I obtained from CH, the password is jsut the key repeated as their documentation states they ignore the password:
[[image: REST Linked Service[3]]

I then have added a REST dataset referencing this linked service:
[image: REST DataSet]

And the testing of the connection works fine.

Problems then arise in the copy data task, I am getting an error when previewing and also when I attempt a copy to blob of 'Invalid Authorization Header':

[image]

I'd be grateful for pointers on where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your Auth error but i notice that you want to add some parameters with your `GET` request in the Request Body.

[image]

I think you need to add parameters in `relativeUrl` [property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-rest#dataset-properties):

> A relative URL to the resource that contains the data. When this
>   property isn't specified, only the URL that's specified in the linked
>   service definition is used. The HTTP connector copies data from the
>   combined URL: [URL specified in linked service]/[relative URL
>   specified in dataset].

Also i suggest you checking the correct REST API format of Search Api you are using.There is no other special features in the ADF REST connector. Just make sure the GET request works locally and duplicate it.